# Serving static files on my own server

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

im setting a django server, but im having problem with my static's file's:

## django settings

```
STATIC_URL = 'http://localproject/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/srv/www/project/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/srv/www/project/public/'
MEDIA_URL = '/public/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

## apache

```
Alias /static/ /srv/www/project/static/'
<Document /srv/www/project/static>
Order allow,deny
Allow form all
</Document>

Alias /public/ /srv/www/project/public/'
<Document /srv/www/project/public>
Order allow,deny
Allow form all
</Document>
```

So, i have the admin without style and the website, for example  http://localproject/public is showing a error about *** Not FlatPage matches the given query ***

yes, im using django.contrib.staticfiles

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im answering maybe that help someone, the problem was that im using apache ***(/etc/apache2/sites-available/project)***, but i was wrong with "use another apache config into the project" ***/srv/www/project/apache/httpd.conf*** and setting my Alias in this last one config, when the Alias config need to be in ***(/etc/apache2/sites-available/project)***

```
using:$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/project
```

and the content for project

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName project
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/project

    <Directory /srv/www/project>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>


    AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /srv/www/project/static/css/$1

    Alias /public/ /srv/www/project/public/
    Alias /static/ /srv/www/project/productos/static/

    <Directory /srv/www/project/productos/static>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/www/project/public>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>


    WSGIDaemonProcess project processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup project

    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/project/apache/django.wsgi

</VirtualHost>
```

my settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/srv/www/project/public/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://project/public/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/srv/www/project/productos/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = 'http://project/static/admin/'
```

And now is working :), remember this is my own server

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

First, `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL+'admin/'`. You can actually use that or change it to `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = 'http://localproject/static/admin/'`. `/static/admin/` is incorrect in your scenario.

Second, Django is still being handed the request, and 'public' is being passed as a slug to the FlatPages view, which is why you're getting that error. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/#serving-files for the proper Apache configuration for staticfiles.